# Ubuntu installer seems to have broken my chipset raid array

Tags: system-installation

I have a Gigabyte GA F2A88XM-D3H Motherboard. Using the AMD chipset raid ROM, I had 3 drives set up as a RAID 5 and a fourth drive as the global hot spare. (I've had the array forever, yes I know chipset raid is not great, and raid 10 is better). I was running windows on the boot drive, and I got another hard drive to install Ubuntu 16.0.4. I removed the old boot drive, installed the new one, and left the RAID drives untouched. After installing Ubuntu, I noticed that the RAID drives were now showing up as individual drives. I went into the option ROM, and saw that while the RAID array is still in the array list, the drives are showing up as non-raid, single drives.

I put the windows boot drive back in, and now I see that the RAID chipset is displaying 3 separate drives instead of the array.

I'm a little surprised that in installing, it would mess with a drive other than the one its installing on. Any idea what happened? or how to revert it?

Answer (score 1):

You encountered this issue because your RAID chipset is only a [fake RAID](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FakeRaidHowto). A fake RAID only takes care to create the RAID array (usual from the BIOS) then a driver enables the RAID features over the operation system which is mostly a software RAID.

When installing Ubuntu, it's possible that you erased the hard drives signatures and then break the RAID array done by your BIOS. Linux generally doesn't support very well fake RAID feature.

I haven't any process to propose for your data recovering, you may try to have a look in your BIOS if you can add the drive back to the array without wipe them, but this implies to add them in the same order than previously. If you have no backup of your files, it's probably a bad idea of doing this before you know what you are doing.

Comment: Fortunately I have the important data backed up, but it would be convenient to recover the whole array. Would the Ubuntu installer format the drives by default or anything? The only drive that ever showed up during installation process was the boot drive. I'm surprised it did anything to the others...

Comment: Ubuntu is not supposed to format the drive (I guess to content of the drive is still present), but because Ubuntu don't have the driver for the soft array, maybe it override the drive signature used by array to know the order to use the disk. If you cannot repair your array from the BIOS utility, you may have a look for a tool dedicated to repair the RAID metadata like http://www.ufsexplorer.com/download_stdrr.php (never tested).